# Rails - get data of associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to RoR, I am trying to get the data of an associated record to display in an index.

I got this to work:

```
<td><%= annotation.documenttype_id %></td>
```

Yet want the value of the name field of the documenttype.
I am using Rails 5. Experiencing Rails so far, it has got to be so simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code i can get that the association is:

> annotation belongs_to document_type

So you can access the document_type from annotation like this:

```
annotation.document_type.name
```

Comment: association is correct; yet documenttype without underscore. So found the fix and simple it is: annotation.documenttype.name

Comment: yes, it should be like this. But we usually follow the convention of two words join with a underscore. Glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`<td><%= annotation.document_type.field_name %></td>`